# How do you parse Bitly response JSON with Aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I've been banging my head trying to use Aeson to parse Bitly responses.
Could someone give me a hint as to what Haskell types should be defined
and how to use Aeson to then parse the following into those types?:

```
// BITLY EXPAND RESPONSE
{
  "data": {
    "expand": [
      {
        "global_hash": "900913",
        "long_url": "http://google.com/",
        "short_url": "http://bit.ly/ze6poY",
        "user_hash": "ze6poY"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_txt": "OK"
}

// BITLY SHORTEN RESPONSE
{
  "data": {
    "global_hash": "900913",
    "hash": "ze6poY",
    "long_url": "http://google.com/",
    "new_hash": 0,
    "url": "http://bit.ly/ze6poY"
  },
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module BitlyClientResponses where

import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L (pack)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict        as M

data DataStatusCodeStatusTxt =
    DSCST { ddata       :: ResponseData
          , status_code :: Integer
          , status_txt  :: String
          }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data ResponseData
  = ExpandResponseData { expand :: [Response]
                       }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Response = ExpandResponse { long_url    :: String -- URI
                               , global_hash :: String
                               , short_url   :: String -- URI
                               , user_hash   :: String
                               -- , hash        :: [String]
                               -- , error       :: String
                               }
              | J String
              | N String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FromJSON DataStatusCodeStatusTxt where
    parseJSON (Object o) = DSCST <$>
                               o .: "data" <*>
                               o .: "status_code" <*>
                               o .: "status_txt"
    parseJSON x = fail $ "FAIL: DataStatusCodeStatusTxt: " ++ (show x)

instance FromJSON ResponseData where
    parseJSON (Object o) =
        case M.lookup "expand" o of
            -- LOST RIGHT HERE
            Just v  -> return $ ExpandResponseData [J ((show o) ++ " $$$ " ++ (show v))]
            Nothing -> return $ ExpandResponseData [N "N"]
    parseJSON x =  fail $ "FAIL: ResponseData: " ++ (show x)

instance FromJSON Response where
    parseJSON (Object o) = ExpandResponse         <$>
                               o .: "long_url"    <*>
                               o .: "global_hash" <*>
                               o .: "short_url"   <*>
                               o .: "user_hash"
                               -- o .: "hash"        <*>
                               -- o .: "error"       <*>
    parseJSON x =  fail $ "FAIL: Response: " ++ (show x)

parseResponse :: String -> Either String DataStatusCodeStatusTxt
parseResponse x = eitherDecode $ L.pack x
```

When I input (hand edited for readability):

```
"{ \"status_code\": 200,
   \"status_txt\": \"OK\",
   \"data\": { \"expand\": [
                            { \"short_url\": \"http:\\/\\/bit.ly\\/LCJq0b\",
                              \"long_url\": \"http:\\/\\/blog.swisstech.net\\/2012\\/06\\/local-postfix-as-relay-to-amazon-ses.html\",
                              \"user_hash\": \"LCJq0b\",
                              \"global_hash\": \"LCJsVy\" }, ...
```

I get back (hand edited too):

```
Right
  (Right
    (DSCST
      {ddata = ExpandResponseData {expand = [J "fromList [(\"expand\",Array (fromList [Object fromList [(\"long_url\",String \"http://blog.swisstech.net/2012/06/local-postfix-as-relay-to-amazon-ses.html\"),(\"global_hash\",String \"LCJsVy\"),(\"short_url\",String \"http://bit.ly/LCJq0b\"),(\"user_hash\",String \"LCJq0b\")], ...
$$$
Array (fromList [Object fromList [(\"long_url\",String \"http://blog.swisstech.net/2012/06/local-postfix-as-relay-to-amazon-ses.html\"),(\"global_hash\",String \"LCJsVy\"),(\"short_url\",String \"http://bit.ly/LCJq0b\"),(\"user_hash\",String \"LCJq0b\")], ...
```

In the code, look for `-- LOST RIGHT HERE`.  I can't figure out how to parse the array of `"expand"`.

It would be great to see how to make progress.  And perhaps I am on the wrong path and someone can set me straight (e.g., maybe the data type I have defined so far is off).

Comment: Why did you define long_url and short_url as [String] and not plain String?

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I had copied the ExpandRequest constructors where you can give multiple URLs.  But the responses should only be `String` as you point out - good catch!  I updated the types.  And maybe that is part of my problem (will try now) - still need to study @abrahamson response too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with using `Aeson` effectively is to call down to `parseJSON` recursively. This is done implicitly when you use the `(.:)` operator, so seeing something like `M.lookup` is usually a bad sign. I'll provide a simplified example: a path of (latitude, longitude) pairs, represented by a JSON array of JSON objects.

```
data Path  = Path  { points :: [Point] }
data Point = Point { lat :: Double, lon :: Double }

-- JSON format looks a bit like this
--
-- { "points": [ {"latitude": 86, "longitude": 23} ,
--               {"latitude": 0,  "longitude": 16} ,
--               {"latitude": 43, "longitude": 87} ] }

instance FromJSON Path where
  parseJSON = withObject "path" $ \o -> 
    Path <$> o .: "points"

instance FromJSON Point where
  parseJSON = withObject "point" $ \o ->
    Point <$> o .: "latitude"
          <*> o .: "longitude"
```

There are two major points to take away from this snippet. Firstly, note the use of `withObject` to quickly constrain that the `Value` passed to `parseJSON` is tagged as an `Object`—it's not significantly different than using pattern matching, but it produces automatic, uniform error messages so it's worth considering.

Secondly, and more importantly, note that I only define `FromJSON` instance which describe the high-level outline of each object. In particular, examine the body of `FromJSON Path`

```
Path <$> o .: "points"
```

All this says is that I need to look into the entry named `"points"` and try to parse it as whatever type is necessary to build a `Path`—in this case, a list of `Point`s, `[Point]`. This use depends upon recursively defined `FromJSON` instances. We need to parse an array, but fortunately there already exists the `FromJSON` instance

```
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON [a] where ...
```

which is interpreted as a JSON array of whatever JSON types `a` can parse as. In our case `a ~ Point`, so we just define that instance

```
instance FromJSON Point where ...
```

and then recursively depend upon the

```
instance FromJSON Double where ...
```

which is quite standard.

---

Another important trick you can use is adjoining multiple parses with `(<|>)`. I'll simplify the `Response` data type a bit where it either parses as a particular `Object` or fails and produces a plain, dynamically typed `Value` as default. First we'll write each parser independently.

```
data Obj = Obj { foo :: String, bar :: String }
         | Dyn Value

okParse :: Value -> Parser Obj
okParse = withObject "obj" (\o -> Obj <$> o .: "foo" <*> o .: "bar")

elseParse :: Value -> Parser Obj
elseParse v = pure (Dyn v)
```

And now we combine them in the actual `FromJSON` instance

```
instance FromJSON Obj where
  parseJSON v = okParse v <|> elseParse v
```

In this case, `aeson` will try to use `okParse` first and, if it fails, fall back on `elseParse`. Since `elseParse` is simply a `pure` value it will never fail and thus provides a "default" fallback.

Comment: As you correctly inferred, I was lost on the intersection of two ideas - how to parse something that is sometimes an JSON array and sometimes a single JSON object.  Using the first half of your "tricks", it now works.  But only for the "expand" case.  Now I need to use your second `(<|>)` trick to handle the "shorten" case.  I will return (soon I hope) with my latest progress.  THANKS!